# android save activity from dying

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have an activity , 
that on some of it's fragments I'm going to database to get data. The problem is on the way back.

When back button pressed the fragment goes and get the data again . 
I need it to get the data only once (the data is not lost).
Whats the right way to do it ?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.from_opening_to_plan, container,
                false);



        setRetainInstance(true); //work only once.


        // --- Sending Data to Server -----//
        startLoading();
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(funcName, h,
                new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    results = ((HashMap<String, Object>) result);
                    stopLoading();
                }
                else{
                    stopLoading();
                }
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

    protected void startLoading() {
        proDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity(),ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
        proDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        proDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        proDialog.setCancelable(false);
        proDialog.show();
    }

    protected void stopLoading() {
        proDialog.dismiss();
        proDialog = null;

        // Build the page from the results.
        makePage();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void makePage() {
        LinearLayout ll_buttons = (LinearLayout) v2
                .findViewById(R.id.buttons_frame);
        LinearLayout ll_question = (LinearLayout) v2
                .findViewById(R.id.question_frame);

        TextView tv = new TextView(container2.getContext());
        String text = (((HashMap) results).get("textPrefix").toString());
        text = text.replace("\r", "\r\n\r\n "); 
          ....
          ....

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     ....
                }
            });
            ll_buttons.addView(b1);
        }

          v2.setBackgroundDrawable(SMApplication.selectedVertical.gd);          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `setRetainInstance(true)` from that fragment's constructor the fragment won't be recreated every time the `Activity` gets recreated, so you can only fetch your data once, if not fetched yet.

Comment: You haven't posted any code so it's not possible to see what happens

Comment: add a code , maybe i should use some thing with onBack() ?

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution (If some one have a better one please post):

added onResume function:

```
private boolean resumeHasRun = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!resumeHasRun) {
        resumeHasRun = true;
        return;
    }
    makePage();
    // Normal case behavior follows
}
```

in the onCreate add :

```
if (resumeHasRun) {
    resumeHasRun = true;
    return;
}
```